# Install /lib/libcrypt.so.1 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have `/lib32/libc.so.6` installed but miss `libcrypt.so.1`.

`apt-file search libcrypt.so.1` only finds `libc6-mips*` and `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1`.

Where do I find 32-bit `libcrypt.so.1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ubuntu 20.04, `libcrypt.so.1` is provided by [`libxcrypt`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libxcrypt/) in the `libcrypt1` package. You need to install the `i386` variant of that:

```
sudo apt install libcrypt1:i386
```

You might need to enable `i386` first:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
```